# Retrofit2 with MailGun in android not working

Tags: android, retrofit2, mailgun

I am having real issues trying to send emails via MailGun using Retrofit2 on an Android application. The code below doesn't give any errors but also does not work, and I do not know enough about how MailGun or Retrofit2 work in order to know even where to start with troubleshooting the below code, and am struggling to find help online.

Here is my MailHandler class.

```
public class MailHandler {

private static final String TAG = "MailHandler";
public static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<domain redacted>/messages/";
public static final String ACCEPT_JSON_HEADER = "Accept: application/json";
public static final String BASIC = "Basic";

String apiKey = "api:key-<redacted>";
String fromText = "Boaty McBoatface<noreply@boatymcboatface.co.uk>";
private MailInterface api;

public interface MailInterface {
    @Headers({ACCEPT_JSON_HEADER})
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/messages")
    Call<Void> authUser (@Header("Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
                         @Field("from") String from,
                         @Field("to") String to,
                         @Field("subject") String subject,
                         @Field("text") String text);

}

public MailHandler() {
    Retrofit retrofit = getAuthAdapter();
    api = retrofit.create(MailInterface.class);
}

public Retrofit getAuthAdapter() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ENDPOINT).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson())).build();
}

public void newEmail(String email) {
    String authHeader = BASIC + " " + Base64.encodeToString(apiKey.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    String subj = "Test Subject";
    String body = "Test Email";
    api.authUser(authHeader, fromText, email, subj, body);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the code you posted you create a Retrofit call object, but never execute it. Your `api.authUser` method returns a typed `Call` object. On that object you can call `enqueue` for an async execution of the network request.

Answer (score 0):

Very late response but the issue here is that you are hitting the api endpoint. (in case it helps someone else)

`https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<domain redacted>/messages/messages/` which doesn't exist. Your base url should just be `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<domain redacted>/` as retrofit is then adding to that when you call your `authUser` method.